# Eclipse IDE C++ not working C++

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, ide, eclipse-cdt

I've downloaded and installed the latest Eclipse, and whenever I try to run a code (after a successful build), I just get a window saying "hello.exe has stopped working", or whatever the name of my program. I can't find any helpful answers online, I've tried what I've seen. I'm using Windows 8.1, Eclipse Juno (latest version), and MinGW. Any idea why?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints !!!Hello World!!!
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Without the code for hello.cpp, and a lot more information about your environment's configuration, we will have difficulty helping you. C++ can crash for many, many reasons, and sadly Windows does a very poor job of telling you anything useful as to why.

Comment: It's just a standard hello world code, but I think it's a problem with Eclipse or MinGW because my original code worked with Xcode on a mac, and obvioulsy hello world should work anywhere

Comment: @aruisdante What information do you think I should provide about the environment's configuration?

Comment: @LAD Are you sure you have installed the MinGW toolchain correctly and completely?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Well, when I got the installer, I checked all the items under Basic Setup,  isn't that enough? It included mingw-developer-toolkit, mingw32-base,mingw32-gcc-ada,mingw32-gcc-fortran,mingw32-gcc-g++,mingw32-gcc-objc and msys-base. Am I meant to install all the other packages too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Juno is not the "(latest version)", for what it's worth.  Kepler, Indigo and Luna are newer.  Juno should work though.

I suggest making sure MinGW works by itself, using a command-line compile, then installing or reinstalling the Eclipse C/C++ Development Tools (CDT).  MinGW needs the proper Visual C++ runtime library to link against.  The standard MinGW installation should provide that or tell you what to download from MSDN.  When the compiler and IDE are separate installs, it just works out better (usually) if you install the compiler first.

Also, get a newer Eclipse.  Juno is fine for Java, but the CDT is a much younger project than Eclipse over all, and showing more growth.

Even with Luna, I had to build twice to get the thing to recognize std::cout.  If you're learning C++, I suggest Code::Blocks and MinGW as a better C/C++ environment.  It's free, open-source and multi-platform, like Eclipse, but began life as a C/C++ IDE.  Eclipse started as a tool for enterprise Java.  For Windows, C::B has a bundle that installs a recent, high-quality build of MinGW alongside that won't conflict with any other MinGW or other compilers.  One install, and it just works.  The feel is nearly the same on Windows and Linux (...except that the Linux repositories usually have a much older version in ready-to-run binary, so you have to rebuild from source to get a current stable version.)

Comment: Hey, thanks! I've downloaded Code::Blocks and it works just fine. A while before your response, I had started using Visual C++ and they're now both working well, so I now have 2 working IDEs :)

Comment: @LAD Good to hear.  About Visual C++, if you are learning Standard C++, beware that the VC++ templates are for Windows-specific applications (with "tmain()" as the entry point and nonstandard headers.)  Use the Application Settings choice on the last page of the Console Project wizard to change to an empty project.  Easiest way to get a true console project without MS "extras".

Comment: Thanks a lot! I always use Empty projects because that's what I've been taught.